# Yii2 how to render radiolist with html content?

Tags: php, html, yii2, radiobuttonlist

I'm trying to make a radio list, with html content inside, where i want to have a title, and an image, from this code:

```
$items=array();
foreach ($templates['user'] as $template) {
    $item = $template['name'];
    $item .= Html::encode("<div>".Html::img($template['preview_image'])."</div>");
    $items[] = $item;
}
```

And then to display it

```
echo Html::radioList('templates', null, $items, ['separator'=>"<hr />",'encode'=>'html']);
```

But it doesn't work. I get the html code in the view. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are encoding your html on the line:

```
$item .= Html::encode("<div>".Html::img($template['preview_image'])."</div>");
```

Try removing `Html::encode()`.

Edit:

Also, try changing the option `encode` to `false`:

```
echo Html::radioList('templates', null, $items, ['separator'=>"<hr />",'encode'=>false]);
```

Comment: Did that, and still doesn't work. I get on the view `<label><input type="radio" name="templates" value="0">Name of the template&lt;div&gt;&lt;img src="http://localhost/project/image/01.jpg" alt=""&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</label>`